# How to pass data to PrimeVue MenuItems

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I have PrimeVue Menu as follows:

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <label class="text-slate-500 text-sm">Doctor Name</label>
    <div class="text-sm">{{ appointment.doctor.name }}</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
    <a href="#"><i class="pi pi-ellipsis-v" @click="toggle"></i></a>
    </span>
    <Menu ref="menu" :model="items" :popup="true" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          label: 'Reschedule',
          command: (event) => {
            this.rescheduleVisible = true
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Mark Completed'
        },
        {
          label: 'Cancel Schedule'
        },
        {
          label: 'Generate Bill'
        },
        {
          label: 'Set Reminder'
        },
        {
          label: 'Send Message'
        },
      ]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(event) {
      console.log(event)
      this.$refs.menu[0].toggle(event);
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this menu in an appointment listing. Now when I click on the `Reschedule` menu item, I need to get the corresponding appointment ID so that I can pass it to the modal popup, which will be visible by setting `rescheduleVisible` as `true` and showing the details about the appointment. How this can be done?

The modal is as shown below:

```
<Dialog v-model:visible="rescheduleVisible" modal header="Reschedule" :style="{ width: '30vw' }">
  <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg">
    <div class="p-2 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
      <div class="grid grid-col-1 gap-3">
        <div class="p-2">
          <div>
            <InputLabel for="appointment_time" value="Date and Time" />
            <Calendar inputId="appointment_time" v-model="form.appointment_time" :showTime="true"
              :showSeconds="false" hourFormat="12" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2">
          <div>
            <InputLabel for="doctor" value="Doctor" />
            <Dropdown v-model="form.doctor_id" :options="doctors" optionLabel="name"
              optionValue="id" placeholder="Select Doctor" :filter="true" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-3">
        <div class="flex justify-end">
          <!-- <SecondaryButton class="ml-2" @click="cancel()">Cancel</SecondaryButton> -->
          <PrimaryButton class="ml-2" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }"
            :disabled="form.processing">
            Reschedule
          </PrimaryButton>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</Dialog>
```

Edit: Appointment Listing

[image: Appointment Listing]

Answer (score 0):

I would add popup to your template and make it visible if `rescheduleVisible` is true. But you need to define `rescheduleVisible` in your data first, otherwise it is not a reactive variable and Vue doesn't know how to watch it.

```
data() {
  return {
    rescheduleVisible: false,
    items: [...
```

Comment: `rescheduleVisible` is working fine. What I need is I need to get the corresponding appointment ID on which the menu is opened. So inside the model, I can show the details about corresponding appointment.

Comment: Where does this appointmentId come from?

Comment: I don't understand your data flow. I see no popup in your code. I see that you do use appointment reference in the template (`appointment.doctor.name`). Isn't it then just using `appointment.id` in your menu's command function not enough?

Comment: It is like this: I have a list of appointments and for each of the appointment, I need to show the menu. When I click on any of the MenuItem, it will show a popup with some of the corresponding appointment detail. Now when I click on the menuitem, the popup opens, but there is no way to pass the id of the appointment to the command function. I will update the question with popup code.

Comment: Ref: https://primevue.org/menu

Comment: I still don't quite get it since setting the prop rescheduleVisible on the child changes it on the parent (i assume). I still don't get your structure to be honest, I miss the parent and since this seems to be related to passing data around components, it is really basic information that is missing. Anyways, I'd try with either store or events (event bus of some type) or setting the prop on the parent directly. Success!

Answer (score 0):

If I get your use case correct then you have a list of appointments and each appointment has a menu that has some children. On click of any children, you need to open a modal and pass the current appointment's id.

**The workaround could be**
I am not sure if there is any event or prop available which can pass the loop's current item information to the Menu component. However, you can use some other logic to do this-

I am assuming your template looks something like this-

```
<div v-for="appointment in appointments">
  <div  class="">
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    ...
    <a href="#"><i class="pi pi-ellipsis-v" @click="toggle"></i></a>
    ...
    <Menu ref="menu" :model="items" :popup="true" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can create a data variable for the selected appointment id-

```
data() {
  return {
    selected: null,
  }
}
```

Then to the `toggle` method, you can pass the current appointment's id-

```
<a href="#"><i class="pi pi-ellipsis-v" @click="toggle($event, appointment.id)"></i></a>
```

and toggle method can set the passed appointment id as selected-

```
toggle(event, appointment_id) {
  this.$refs.menu[0].toggle(event);
  this.selected = appointment_id
},
```

Finally, on any children's click, you can open the modal and pass the selected appointment's id which is inside the `selected` variable, and on the modal's close, reset the `selected` variable again.

Not sure if this is the right way or not but couldn't find many examples of using PrimeVue Menu component in for loop.

Comment: I am happy, it worked. :-D